# Applying multiple filters to dataset from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to create a report to look-up employees. The users want to be able to enter one of the following to locate a record: LastName OR FirstName OR Department OR EmplID.

I want to use an stored procedure that already exist but it used by other reports so it cannot be modified.

I am trying to setup the parameters as filters on the dataset and it works with ONE filter. As soon as I add another one it stops working.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, keeping your original SP is to dump the results of the SP into a temp table then filter that temp table by your parameters.

Let's say your SP currently Returns

`EmpID, DeptID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, EmpDeptID, EmpDept`

then you could do something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE #t(EmpID int, DeptID int, EmpFirstName varchar(50), EmpLastName varchar(50), DeptName varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #t
    EXEC myStoredProc

SELECT * FROM #t
    WHERE EmpID LIKE '%' + @EmpID + '%'
        OR DeptID LIKE '%' + @DeptID + '%'
        OR EmpFirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'
        OR EmpLastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%'
```

or something similar...